# Applying sonarqube build breaker plugin to existing projects

Tags: sonarqube

So we use sonarqube/sonar in my current employer and have many existing projects on the sonarqube platform. I have been asked to go through these existing projects and ensure they have the buildbreaker plugin set to the default as some have been changed to true, the problem is they run into the hundreds and I don't fancy going through every project and checking this.

Is there a quicker way to change this? Maybe a script to run? A google search has revealed nothing, I am hoping someone has experienced this before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was actually ridiculously easy, setting>configuration>build breaker set to required value when not in a project will go back through all existing projects and change to the required settings.

This just means that to set an individual projects settings you will need to manually alter them again once you have changed the global settings.